# Prevent going back when hardware back button is pressed in Ionic 4 App

Tags: javascript, angular6, ionic4

```html
    this.platform.backButton.subscribe(()=> {
         const alert = await this.alertController.create({
         header: 'Confirm!',
         message: 'Do you want to go back!!!',
         buttons: [
         {
            text: 'Yes',
            handler: () => {
            // Previous page loaded
         }
         }, {
            text: 'No',
            handler: () => {
              //Page should not go back.
              //This is where i want to write code,if the user clicks 
              No and the back button function should be disabled.
              //Only when the user presses Yes,the page will go to 
              previous.
              }
            }
         ]
      });
    })
```

I dont know how to handle when the user presses no,i.e.Disable the back button function or event.

Comment: Are you using confirmation popup?

Comment: Yeah i have to,but on the above code,i just used an alert for representation.User should decide whether to go back or stay on the current page.When the alert closes,page is redirected back.

Comment: Dont use this alert use `ion-alert` refer here https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/alert

Comment: why you have to use this, is that it emits the value pressed by the user. In your case Yes or No. Then we can easily identify which button the user is pressed and we can handle them accordingly

Comment: @Sivaramakrishnan Alert is not the issue,i want to handle the handle back button from going back.

Comment: then how will you identify the button pressed by the user?

Comment: @Sivaramakrishnan No No The problem is not with that alert or pop up.It is with the platform.backButton event emitter. I wanna prevent from going back.

Comment: I edited the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i solved the issue.As the event emitted from the backButton is an promise.If I dont need to go back,i just reject that promise.

```js
    this.platform.backButton.subscribe(()=> {
         const alert = await this.alertController.create({
         header: 'Confirm!',
         message: 'Do you want to go back!!!',
         buttons: [
         {
            text: 'Yes',
            handler: () => {
            // Previous page loaded
         }
         }, {
            text: 'No',
            handler: () => {
            reject()
              }
            }
         ]
      });
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way to prevent the back button

```
this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(9999, () => {
      this.dismiss();
    });
```

Comment: ERROR : Property 'preventDefault' does not exist on type 'BackButtonDetail'

Comment: ERROR : Property 'dismiss' does not exist on type 'CreateOrgComponent'.

Comment: I found the solution. As the event emitted is an Promise, i can reject the promise if i dont want to go back.Thanks for your help.